# MVVM and Silverlight help

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am trying to learn the MVVM pattern using Silverlight. There are tons of videos and blogs. I understand it in a high level, but cant seem to get my own implementation of it.

I got the following View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" Height="200"/>
        <Button Name="btn1" Width="200" Height="20" Margin="100,268,100,12" Click="btn1_Click"/>

    </Grid> </UserControl>
```

In my VM, I have:
namespace SilverlightApplication1.ViewModel

```
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Model.UserModel m_model;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            m_model = new Model.UserModel();
        }

        public string Name 
        {
            get
            {
                return m_model.Name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != m_model.Name)
                {
                    m_model.Name = value;
                    InvokePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void InvokePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }


    }
}
```

and in my Model:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1.Model
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to simulate a button click and update the property so that it can fire the property changed event. I tried hard coding the property on the MainPage code behind like this:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.ViewModel vm = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
            vm.Name = "Test";
        }
```

Shouldnt this update the property (for Name) and raise the propertychanged event? I have seen other examples do something similar to this. I dont understand as to what is subscribing to the event

Can anyone shine some light?

Comment: Things look right on the surface, however, did you _set breakpoints_ or do any troubleshooting? what were your findings? What happens when you run the app? Everything works except your NotifyPropertyChange ?

Comment: The PropertyChanged event is always Null. When I set breakpoints to the property, it updates, however the event never gets raised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, to fix it, try this code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.ViewModel vm = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
            this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = vm;
            vm.Name = "Test";
        }
```

Note: I know you just learning MVVM, but after you're comfortable with this paradigm, you should adopt a framework so you can focus on things besides the MVVM plumbing. In saying that, doing things in the code-behind is not the MVVM way, like setting the data context.  However, I assume you're just experimenting and learning, so it's fine for now.

Comment: That worked! Setting the datacontext of layoutroot to the VM does what exactly?

Comment: The WPF/Silverlight framework needs to know what datasource to use for data binding.  _data context is the data source that is used for binding_ from MSDN. Your telling the framework to use your CLR object (i.e. your view-model) for the datasource, which is used for binding.

Comment: Can you elaborate on you note? Adopt a framework? You mean like Prism? Also, how will you do things differently in an MVVM way instead of setting the Data Context in the Code Behind?

Comment: Sure: a framework will make it a bit easier to ensure your datacontext is set and your property changed events are wired up and much more. take a look for yourself, : 1. http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/  2. http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/

Answer (score 0):

I think the step you're missing here is setting the WPF form's datacontext to an instance of your viewmodel.In your xaml set your UserControl datacontext to a new viewmodel like below:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
  <vm:ViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Then just do normal sets in your vm and it should bubble up the changes to your binding.

Comment: I added that. PropertChanged event is still null.